# String modifications assistance

Tags: java, string

I've spend the day working on these two classes.  I've come further than I was expecting to yet needless to say I'm running into issues.

Basically I have to take an inputted String and return only the uppercase letters, every second letter, the entire string but with all vowels exchanged with an underscore, number of vowels in the string, and lastly positions of all vowels in the string.

I specifically designed my tester class, I believe correctly, to have a menu to try each command separately so I'm able to test each one.

This is the tester class..

```
//******************************************
// LetterTest.java 
// Written by Sanchez
// 2013
//*******************************************

//===========================================
// This program tests the CharAPI class.
//===========================================

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LetterTest {

public static void main(String[] args){
    //create Scanner for user input
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    //get user input
        System.out.println("Please enter a string of letters");
        String input = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("\nChoose an option: "
        +"\n1 - Uppercase, "
        +"\n2 - Every Second Letter, "
        +"\n3 - Replace vowels "
        +"\n4 - Number of vowels "
        +"\n5 - Positions of vowels");
    int choice = in.nextInt();

    //Call the method based on user choice

if (choice == 1)  {
        //each method returns a String
    System.out.println(LetterAPI.bigLetters(input) );
}
else if (choice ==2)  {
    System.out.println(LetterAPI.secondLetter(input) );
}
else if (choice ==3)  { 
    System.out.println(LetterAPI.vowelsGone(input) );
}
else if (choice ==4)  { 
    System.out.println(LetterAPI.vowelNumber(input) );
}
else {
    System.out.println(LetterAPI.vowelPositions(input) );
}
}
}
```

That seems to be working pretty well and I'm happy with it.

The issue I'm having is in my class with the objects that do the manipulation
I've used the // on a couple things just so I could get it to compile.  The 1st, 2nd, and 4th, straight up don't return anything.  The third one only exchanges the last letter for an underscore even if it's not a vowel, and the fifth one works pretty well except I'd like to add 1 to all the numbers so the results start at 1 and not 0.  I understand that there's a lot going on here but I've spent the day on it and am finally submitting that I am in dire need of help.

This is the code for the objects...

```
//******************************************
// LetterAPI.java 
// Written by Sanchez
// 2013
//*******************************************

//===========================================
// Objects of this class manipulate an inputted string.
//===========================================

import java.util.Scanner;

//contains a set of methods for maniuplaing the string
public class LetterAPI {

//print only uppercase letters
public static String bigLetters(String input) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <input.length(); i++) {
    char currentLetter=input.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(currentLetter))
    result = result;
    }
    return result;


}
//print every second letter
public static String secondLetter(String input) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <input.length(); i++) {
    //result = input.charAt(input);
    }
    return result;


}
//all vowels replaced by underscores
public static String vowelsGone(String input) {
    String result ="aeiouAEIOU";
    for (int i = 0; i<result.length();i++) {
    result=input.replace(result.charAt(i), '_');
    }
    return result;


}
//the numbers of vowels
public static String vowelNumber(String input) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <input.length(); i++) {

        if (Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'a' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'e' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'i' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'o' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'u') {
            i++;
        }

    }
    return result;

}
//the positions of all vowels
public static String vowelPositions(String input) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <input.length(); i++) {

        if (Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'a' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'e' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'i' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'o' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'u') {
            result = result + i + " ";
        }
    }
    return result;

}
}
```

===UPDATE===

Thank you everyone!  I've made some progress thank god.  I've gotten the 3rd and 4th to work great.  The first one was giving only the last uppercase but now is repeating my input.  The second one is just giving me back the 1st letter.  As for the last one I tried parenthesis but I seemed to have broke it so I put it back for now.  That's not as critical..at least it works!  If I can't figure that out I'll have to put a note that the count starts at 0.  But the first two are killing me..at least it compiles.  Here's where I'm at so far...

```
//******************************************
// LetterAPI.java 
// Written by Sanchez
// 2013
//*******************************************

//===========================================
// Objects of this class manipulate an inputted string.
//===========================================

import java.util.Scanner;

//contains a set of methods for maniuplaing the string
public class LetterAPI {

//print only uppercase letters
public static String bigLetters(String input) {
    String result = "";
    char cl;
    for (int i = 0; i <input.length(); i++) {
    cl=input.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isUpperCase(cl))
    input = input + cl;
    }
    return input;


}
//print every second letter
public static String secondLetter(String input) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i=0; i<input.length(); i+=2) {
    input = input + input.charAt(i) + " ";
    }
    return input;


}
 //all vowels replaced by underscores
public static String vowelsGone(String input) {
    String vowels ="aeiouAEIOU";
    for (int i = 0; i<vowels.length();i++) {
    input=input.replace(vowels.charAt(i), '_');
    }
    return input;


}
//the numbers of vowels
public static String vowelNumber(String input) {
    String result = "";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <input.length(); i++) {

        if (Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'a' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'e' || Character.toLowerCase(    input.charAt(i)) == 'i' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'o' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'u') {
            count++;
            result = count + " ";
        }

    }
    return result;

}
//the positions of all vowels
public static String vowelPositions(String input) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i <input.length(); i++) {

        if (Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'a' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'e' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'i' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'o' || Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)) == 'u') {
            result = result + i + " ";
        }
    }
    return result;

}
}
```

Comment: `bigLetters`: What do you think `result = result` is going to do?  What do you want to do instead?  `secondLetter`: The third expression in a `for` is something the program will do every time through the loop.  Often, it's something like `i++`, which means "add 1 to `i`".  But it doesn't have to be.  Can you think of using something besides `i++` that might do what you need?

Comment: `vowelsGone`:  You set `result` to a string of vowels.  The first time through the loop, you use `result` to get the vowel, then you change `result` to something else.  The second time, is `result` still going to be a string of vowels?  If not, how are you going to get the vowel you need?  `vowelNumber`: You need an integer `i` that goes through the string, and you need a different integer to keep the count.  You can't use `i` for both at the same time.  Also, I recommend changing `vowelNumber` so that it returns an `int`.

Comment: `vowelPositions`:  You say you want to add 1 to your answers before adding to the string.  Fine, just do it.  Just be aware that `result = result + i + 1 + " "` won't work, because that first *appends* `i` to `result` as a string, then it appends `1` to `result` as a string.  Parentheses will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

1. In part 1, you do this: `result = result;`  That is nonsensical.  It does nothing.
2. In part 2, the compilation error is because you are trying to *assign* a `char` to a `String`.  That's not legal.  But it is also not what you should be trying to do.  (Think "append", not "assign" ...)
3. In part 3, the first mistake is this: `String result = "aeiouAEIOU";`.  In fact, it should be `String result = input;`.
4. In part 4, you are counting all vowels, not each different vowel.  You also need to turn the count (or counts) into a `String` (in result).
5. About part 5 you say: *"works pretty well except I'd like to add 1 to all the numbers"*.  So do it!

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure how to put an update to my question so I edited it.  I made much progress and am now compiling but not getting the correct results.  Any ideas?

Comment: result = result + (i + 1) + " ". Since the i + 1 is in parentheses and they're both numbers, the + will be treated as an addition of numbers, instead of a string append. Then the result of the addition will be converted to a string.

Comment: *"Any ideas"* - Frankly, you've already had more than enough hints.